# Is there any differrence between "unrelenting" and "relentless"

Tags: synonyms

Are they replaceable synonyms or should they be used depending on the context?

EG:

> - My most candid and unrelenting critic.
> - My most candid and relentless critic.

Answer (score 1):

"**relentless**" in the Cambridge Dictionary:

> - continuing in a severe or extreme way;
> - continuing in a determined way without any interruption;

"**unrelenting**" in the Cambridge Dictionary:

> - extremely determined; never becoming weaker or admitting defeat;
> - extremely determined; never weakening or ending;

---

According tho these definitions, the two words are synonyms.